# Tomcat 6.0 and Eclipse. Multiple instances of the server behave differently

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, instances

I have Tomcat 6.0 installation on my Win7 PC. I used 64/32bit windows installation.
In Eclipse I was able to set paths and set server to use my Tomcat installation. Everything seems working fine until I run server from inside Eclipse.

I noticed that http://localhost:8080/index.html page is not available (Tomcat default home page). I also can't access http://localhost:8080/axis2. I have Axis2 installed too.

Since I am struggling to make simple axix2 web service for long time, I am thinking maybe this Eclipse instance of Tomcat is adding to my issues?

When I start Tomcat from windows GUI everything works as I expect.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running tomcat ? Via the SysDeo eclipse plugin for tomcat OR you have a web app on your eclipse j2ee perspective and deploying the web app as "Run on server" from the "Run as" menu ?

Comment: @ganguly: "SysDeo" and "j2ee", are you sure you're developing with most recent tools? I haven't seen them in Eclipse for over 5 years.

Comment: that was a oops moment for me .. lemme see what am I missing :(

Comment: @ganguly: "Eclipse for Java EE" should be all what you need. http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise

Comment: @BalusC I am using the same. Sysdeo is a plugin I have been using for 4 years now which gives you three small icons in your eclipse to start/stop/restart your tomcat. I do not use it any more , but was under the opinion lot of people must be using it . I was clearly wrong. Any ways thanks a lot for your effort at directing me to the right path .. kudos :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eclipse does by default not take control over the Tomcat installation and all of its pre-deployed webapps, instead it just uses its sole server engine and uses the workspace metadata as deploy space. When you start such a server configuration from inside Eclipse, all of the pre-deployed webapps will just be plain ignored, including Tomcat's default homepage.

To let Eclipse take control over the Tomcat installation, you need to doubleclick the Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view to get its configuration, then at the left column, under *Server Locations*, you need to select *Use Tomcat installation* (note, when it is grayed out, read the section leading text! It needs to be published without any projects).

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer BalusC, but I feel like everytime I do this Eclipse ends up trashing my Tomcat instance at some point and I have to reinstall everything.

Comment: @jonathan: Rightclick > *Clean* is magnificient. Also, you should realize that this Tomcat instance is supposed to be used *exclusively* by Eclipse this way. If you want a standalone Tomcat without Eclipse's intervention, then just setup another one, perhaps on a different port.

Comment: Yes. It is grayed out. I am trying my best. But I really don't understand what does this mean: "Specify the server path (i.e. catalina.base) and deploy path. Server must be published with no modules present to make changes."

Comment: Rightclick Tomcat, in *Add and Remove projects* remove all projects, then rightclick and *Publish* Tomcat. This way it's published with no modules present.

Comment: Clean usually works for simple projects, but more complex deployments involving a dozen projects generally cause problems.

Comment: @jonathan: Then you first need to do a *Project > Clean*. Or even close and reopen those projects. I've never had the need to reinstall the server or something and I use it this way for almost a decade.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clean worked. Excuse my ignorance. I don't get this concept of publishing a tomcat server? So server is visible to projects? Also my configuration path in Server Overview showing an error. right now it is showing "/Servers2/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config" (with little red X). What should I put there?

Comment: "Publishing" is the step of copying/refreshing/removing source files in the deploy space. As to the error, what's the error message? Check *Markers* tab if you can't find it.

Comment: No specific info about error. It just says "1 error detected"... Anyway I clicked Browse button next to it and selected Server/Tomcat... (instead of Server2/Tomcat...). Error disappeared. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal.  In the **Package Explorer**, you can click the **Servers** folder and view the configuration files that the Eclipse instance is using, specifically **server.xml** and **context.xml**.  You can edit this configuration to match your specific requirements.

You may also want to check out the section titled **Tomcat Publishing Options** in this link here: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/2.0/newandnoteworthy/server.php

I favor this approach because when WTP inevitably corrupts my configuration once every two weeks, I don't have to reinstall Tomcat, I can just delete the server and reconfigure it.