# HTTP 404 Error when running a Hello World servlet with Tomcat 7 in Eclipse 3.7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I followed the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/3/Tomcat-Hello-World-Servlet-using-Eclipse-IDE) to create a Hello World servlet in a new dynamic web project in eclipse.  But when I got to the section marked "5. Run Your Servlet Code", the application failed to run (I got a 404 error message in the browser).  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any messages about the deployment of the app. what happened when you tried to deploy it?

Comment: Get the URL you use correct.  There's no good reason to touch the server.xml.  If Eclipse is modifying it, I'd suggest that you stop using Eclipse.

Comment: @duffymo Eclipse only modifies it when add/removing webapps from the Tomcat instance.

Comment: There's no reason at all to do so.  It's a poor design.  Deploy a WAR and leave that server.xml alone.

Comment: @duffymo The reason is you can control the context path through eclipse.

Comment: Nope, IntelliJ does it without touching the server.xml.  Get a smarter IDE.

Comment: @Duffy: Eclipse is configurable to do so. By default, it creates own copy of `server.xml` in *Servers* project. But it's configurable to "Use Tomcat Installation" instead and thus touch its `server.xml`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114455 This is not IDE's own thing, but enduser's own choice. The smartness must then be questioned in enduser's side.

Comment: @CodeMed It seems like your build path is not setup correctly. Is your source code in a source folder? Check the project build path by right-clicking on it.

Comment: @CodeMed No, that is correct. `Java Resources` isn't a real folder, it's just a view for Eclipse. In the Project Properties, you can look through the `Deployment Assembly` for anything that is missing.

Comment: @CodeMed No that is correct. Honestly, just JAR your file (eclipse export) and copy paste it into your Tomcat's installation `webapps` directory and startup Tomcat from /{installationDir}/bin/startup.bat`.

Comment: @CodeMed You can drop the `war` (not jar sorry, but that might work too) directly into the webapps folder. In your Tomcat installation directory, there is a `bin` folder with a `startup.bat` file you can execute from the command line.

Comment: @CodeMed Haha, I get you dude, np! It's hard to say because I'm making a million assumptions about what you about Java, Eclipse, and Tomcat. Unless I have your project in front of me, I can only offer suggestions. Try going through the tutorial steps again.

Answer (score 0):

If the server says ClassNotFoundException, it means the Class is Not Found Exception :-)

Did you check your **deploy** and **work** directories inside tomcat? verify you really have the class inside your war (or uncompressed in the work dir)

If not: put them manually to check your code works; then check why your eclipse or netb doesn't copy them to the server deployement dir